# Get combinations of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, combinations

Let us consider the following array:

```
$dataArray = array(
    'A' => array(
            'A1',
            'A2',
        ),
    'B' => array(
            'B1',
            'B2',
            'B3',
        ),
    'C' => array(
            'C1',
            'C2',
            'C3',
        )
);
```

What is the fastest and best-performance loop may I follow the get the following output:

```
A1 B1 C1
A1 B1 C2
A1 B1 C3

A1 B2 C1
A1 B2 C2
A1 B2 C3

A1 B3 C1
A1 B3 C2
A1 B3 C3

A2 B1 C1
A2 B1 C2
A2 B1 C3

....

An Bn Cn
```

Please note that the number of sub-array is dynamic, same thing for their lengths.

I will need to do treatment inside the iteration, once I reach each line as in the given output.

This is what I tried till now, but it's not giving the right result at the beginning of the loop:

```
foreach($dataArray as $k => $vals1){
    foreach($vals1 as $k1 => $val1){
        $currentVars[$k] = $val1;
        foreach($dataArray as $k2 => $vals2){
            foreach($vals2 as $val2){
                if($k == $k2) break;
                $currentVars[$k2] = $val2;
                echo implode(" ", $currentVars).chr(10);
            }
            unset($dataArray[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A1 B1
A1 B2
A1 B3
A1 B3 C1
A1 B3 C2
A1 B3 C3
A2 B1 C3
A2 B2 C3
A2 B3 C3
A2 B3 C1
A2 B3 C2
A2 B3 C3
A2 B1 C1
A2 B1 C2
A2 B1 C3
A2 B2 C1
A2 B2 C2
A2 B2 C3
A2 B3 C1
A2 B3 C2
A2 B3 C3
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Please paste some of your code.

Comment: if there is a possibility for An , why did you stop first line at A1 B1 C1.

Comment: I'm just considerating that the provided source will contains a main rray with 3  sub-arrays, the An is here only to explain that the length is unknown. 
I've just edited the post and added what i've tried.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, you're right Ryan , what is about performace is that the sub-array might contains over 50k values, and for at least 5 sub-arrays and some nice stuff inside the loop, you may see how heavy it is.

Comment: Just for the orientation in the duplicate code. `$data` is just your `$dataArray` array. And since you have an associative array, you have to assign your array keys to a variable, e.g. `$keys = array_keys($dataArray);` and then use it in the second foreach loop: `foreach ($data[$count] as $v2)` -> `foreach ($data[$keys[$count]] as $v2)` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you rizier123 for the answer. Your code is working perfectly, except that for me, i'll have to do the whole combinations beofre starting process over the result, this will take too much memory i guess.